# Best practise for updating data in a AbstractTableModel in a non AWT thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I've sub classed `AbstractTableModel` for use as the model for my `JTable`. Whenever data is added to I call `fireTableRowsInserted()` in the AWT thread. All access to my underlying container is made thread safe by using synchronized methods.

This pattern has been working fine for me so far. However now I want to remove data from the list I've realized I have a threading issue. If I remove a row and call `fireTableRowsDeleted()` in the AWT thread I can still get a call to `getValueAt()` for a row index that now no longer exists.

What is best practice for performing operation on a the table model outside the AWT thread?

Comment: that's depends if (overide) methods are inside AbstractTableModel and if methods FireXxxXxx and called from outside Model or not, because I don't see any difference between addRow and removeRow on both sides (Model and View too)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best practice IMHO is to avoid doing it. Wrap every access to the model from another thread inside a Runnable and use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to update the model.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to remove the data from the EDT. Any operation that results in `AbstractTableModel` firing a change event needs to be done in the EDT.